# Read a toml file in java 2022

Tags: java, toml, jackson-dataformats-text

After a quick research, I found the following three libraries for parsing Toml files in java.
[toml4j](https://github.com/mwanji/toml4j)
[tomlj](https://github.com/tomlj/tomlj)
[jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/2.14/toml)

What I am looking for is a library that can parse toml files without a corresponding POJO class. While both `toml4j`, and `tomlj` can achieve that, they do not seem to be maintained.

`jackson-dataformats-text` on the other is actively maintained but I can not parse a toml file without the corresponding POJO class.
Is there a way to create a dynamic class in java that I can use to parse any toml file?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to read a TOML file without a POJO, FasterXML Jackson libraries are a great choice. The simplest method is to just read the content as a `java.util.Map`:

```
final var tomlMapper = new TomlMapper();
final var data = tomlMapper.readValue(new File("config.toml"), Map.class);
```

After that, the content of the file will be available in `data`.

If you need even lower level parsing, all formats supported by FasterXML Jackson can be read using the stream API. In case you need that, read about the stream API on the core module: [FasterXML/jackson-core](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core), just make sure you use the right factory class (`TomlFactory` instead of `JsonFactory`).